# Openlayers trackline length (include altitude)

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I using OpenLayers 4, and I want to get length at the LineString.
My code snippet:

```js
 var trackline = new ol.geom.LineString(points);  //points an array with coordinates
 var featurething = new ol.Feature({geometry: trackline});
 var linestyle = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({width: 4, color: 'rgba(0, 180, 220, 1)'}) 
    }); 
 featurething.setStyle(linestyle);
 vectorSource.addFeature( featurething );
```

How get the trackline length, include altitude?

[image: Sample]

Thanks!

Comment: does your data have altitude? then you can code it. it's about math i think.

Comment: No, but maybe I can get it.
Thanks!